# How to "unpair", "remove" Bluetooth device in Windows with C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, bluetooth, pairing

I faced a problem. I need to unpair, or remove bluetooth device from windows.
Here, I have my phone Redmi paired

[image]

And I need to unpair it, so basically I want to achieve the same effect as pressing "Remove device" button

I tried this, but it didn't work for me, since this solution disconnects bluetooth device, but it still stays paired: [How to disconnect a bluetooth device from C# .Net in Win7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829164/how-to-disconnect-a-bluetooth-device-from-c-sharp-net-in-win7)

I am using C# WPF and InTheHand library for pairing, but it does not have unpair functionality

How do I achieve my goal? Thank

Comment: I do not know how it is implemented in 32feet but you have to call [BluetoothRemoveDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothremovedevice) function.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko thanks, I will try that. In InTheHand lib (as I understand the same thing as 32feet) there is no remove device function
Thanks a lot

Comment: @MikePetrichenko how exactly should I call it? Have not much of experience with these things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To unapir classic Bluetooth device you have to call [BluetoothRemoveDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothremovedevice) function.

For .NET it can be imported as below

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS
{
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8)]
  public Int64 ullLong;
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
  public Byte rgBytes_0;
  [FieldOffset(1)]
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
  public Byte rgBytes_1;
  [FieldOffset(2)]
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
  public Byte rgBytes_2;
  [FieldOffset(3)]
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
  public Byte rgBytes_3;
  [FieldOffset(4)]
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
  public Byte rgBytes_4;
  [FieldOffset(5)]
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
  public Byte rgBytes_5;
};

[DllImport("BluetoothAPIs.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
static extern UInt32 BluetoothRemoveDevice(
  [param: In, Out] ref BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS pAddress);
```

Here is how to call it:

```
UInt32 Unpair(Int64 Address)
{
  BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS Addr = new BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS();
  Addr.ullLong = Address;
  return BluetoothRemoveDevice(ref Addr);
}
```

Please not that this function allows to unpair Classic Bluetooth devices only. To unpair Bluetooth LE devices you have to use other way based on WinRT.

Comment: This actually solved a huge problem for me... thanks a lot!
edit: I put this to use in a very simple program, full source's on [GitHub](https://github.com/lflfm/btRemover), for those who may need it.